Perform validation after unnesting array based on a delimiter and suffix column values
Below is my table:



ordrnbr
vehiclename
description
id
totprice
ind_price




132
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000



135
toyota
abc@21000@bsd@2300
2aqE
23300



138
honda
abc@2100
3xDY
2100



141
kia
text
6iPQ
10000



145
Mazda
null
90ER
9000



147
BMW
null
69TY
90000




Here in the description column, it is represented as key@value (when delimiter '@' is present) i.e., k1@v1@k2@v2@k3@v3
I need to split the description column based on the delimiter @ and retrieve the values and determine if each value is >=10000. If the value is >=10000, then i need to duplicate that row and suffix ordrnbr  by -1,-2 and -3 respectively depending upon the number of txn's which are more than 10000 for that ordrnbr and the ind_price column should have this value captured i.e.,



ordrnbr
vehiclename
description
id
totprice
ind_price




132-1
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000
21000


132-2
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000
23000


132-3
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000
41000


135-1
toyota
abc@21000@bsd@2300
2aqE
23300
21000


141-1
kia
text
6iPQ
10000
10000


147-1
BMW
null
69TY
90000
90000



If the @value is less than 10000 then it needs to be filtered out.
Also, if the description column does not contain the delimiter, then the corresponding totprice column should be considered and if it is less than 10000 then it needs to be filtered out otherwise the ordrnbr should be prefixed with -1,-2,-3 respectively.
I tried using STRING_TO_ARRAY for splitting on description column based on delimiter @ and using unnest to duplicate records.

In your case, it is interesting that you need to get a two-dimensional array from a string.
Therefore, we use the ORDINALITY value from UNNEST.
Since we need a sequence (key, value), we will pair through (n-1)/2.
For n={1,2, 3,4, 5,6} get(n-1)/2 as{0,0, 1,1, 2,2}. This is value for group by.
See example
with suffixes as (
select ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2 N
  ,max(case when nr%2=1 then elem end) Nkey
  ,cast(max(case when nr%2=0 then elem end) as int) Nval
from test t
left join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t.description, '@'))
                    WITH ORDINALITY AS a(elem, nr) ON true
group by ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2
)
select concat(t.ordrnbr,'-',row_number()over(partition by t.ordrnbr order by s.N))ordrnbr
  , vehiclename,    description,    id, totprice
  ,coalesce(s.Nval,totprice) ind_price
from test t
left join suffixes s on s.ordrnbr=t.ordrnbr
where s.Nval>=10000 or (s.Nval is null and totPrice>=10000)

output



ordrnbr
vehiclename
description
id
totprice
ind_price




132-1
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000
21000


132-2
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000
23000


132-3
tesla
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000
1saR
84000
41000


135-1
toyota
abc@21000@bsd@2300
2aqE
23300
21000


141-1
kia
text
6iPQ
10000
10000


147-1
BMW
null
69TY
90000
90000



Demo with details
There Key-Value pairs from string, not filtered
select ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2 N
  ,min(nr)nr1,max(nr) nr2
  ,max(case when nr%2=1 then elem end) Nkey
  ,max(case when nr%2=0 then elem end) Nval
  ,max(description) description
from test t
left join lateral unnest(string_to_array(t.description, '@'))
                    WITH ORDINALITY AS a(elem, nr) ON true
group by ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2 
order by ordrnbr,(nr-1)/2 ;




ordrnbr
n
nr1
nr2
Nkey
nval
description




132
0
1
2
123
21000
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000


132
1
3
4
bsd
23000
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000


132
2
5
6
wer
41000
123@21000@bsd@23000@wer@41000


135
0
1
2
abc
21000
abc@21000@bsd@2300


135
1
3
4
bsd
2300
abc@21000@bsd@2300


138
0
1
2
abc
2100
abc@2100


141
0
1
1
text
null
text




its a brilliant solution. The thing is if the description field does not contain delimiter @, then that record should be filtered out if the totprice is <10000. How do we achieve this? Have amended my question.

Try where s.Nval>=10000 or (s.Nval is null and totPrice>=10000)

Perfect - that nicely works!

Is there a way that we could implement this solution without WITH ORDINALITY as the API that i use i.e., DuckDB for postgres implementation does not support  this?Can you please hep me on this?

See example (https://dbfiddle.uk/7_nfgVZo).
